# laravel migration raise could not find driver under docker

Tags: laravel, docker

I installed laravel 5.8(with mysql) app under docker with php:7.1-apache
and running the migration I got error that could not find driver :

```
root@3b62eed328c1:/var/www/ticketly_docker_root# php artisan migrate

In Connection.php line 664:
                                                                                                                                                              
  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')  
                                                                                                                                                              

In PDOConnection.php line 31:
                         
  could not find driver  
                         

In PDOConnection.php line 27:
                         
  could not find driver
```

In my _Docker/web/Dockerfile.yml file I have mysqli, pdo and pdo_mysql installed :

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    python \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    nano \
    mc \
    git-core \
    curl \
    build-essential \
    openssl \
    libssl-dev \
    libgmp-dev \
    libldap2-dev \
    netcat \
    locate \
    && git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git \
    && cd node \
    && git checkout v12.0.0 \
    && ./configure \
     && make \
     && make install

  RUN  docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-webp-dir=/usr/include/  --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/


  # Install Composer
    RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer



    RUN  docker-php-ext-install gd mysqli pdo pdo_mysql  zip gmp bcmath pcntl ldap sysvmsg exif \
&& a2enmod rewrite


COPY virtualhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

and entering in the bash I check installed modules:

```
#  php -m 
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gmp
hash
iconv
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]

root@ff277e39b8f3:/var/www/ticketly_docker_root#  php -v
PHP 7.1.33 (cli) (built: Oct 25 2019 06:33:10) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

I see mysqli, pdo_mysql installed.

In _Docker/docker-compose.yml I have :

```
db:
    container_name: ticketly_db
    image: mysql:5.7.28
    restart: always
    environment:
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=DockerTicketly
        - MYSQL_USER=docker_user
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=4321
        - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=false
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=321

    volumes:
        - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:/var/lib/mysql
```

and in .env of app:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db

DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=DockerTicketly
DB_USERNAME=docker_user
DB_PASSWORD=4321
```

What did I miss in the installation ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK:**

I added into _Docker/web/Dockerfile.yml lines :

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    python \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    nano \
    mc \
    git-core \
    curl \
    build-essential \
    openssl \
    libssl-dev \
    libgmp-dev \
    libldap2-dev \
    netcat \
    locate \
    && git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git \
    && cd node \
    && git checkout v12.0.0 \
    && ./configure \
     && make \
     && make install

  RUN  docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-webp-dir=/usr/include/  --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/


  # Install Composer
    RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer


    RUN  docker-php-ext-install gd pdo pdo_mysql  zip gmp bcmath pcntl ldap sysvmsg exif \
&& a2enmod rewrite

    RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

COPY virtualhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

but after recompile I got the same errors
Are commands above correct?

In .env:

```
# I tried both variants below after cache clearing. Which of them have I to use ?
DB_CONNECTION=mysqli 
# DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db

DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=DockerTicketly
DB_USERNAME=docker_user
DB_PASSWORD=4321
```

My current confuguration:

```
# php -v
\PHP 7.1.33 (cli) (built: Oct 25 2019 06:33:10) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
root@a03a8839fff2:/var/www/ticketly_docker_root# php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gmp
hash
iconv
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib


# php -i
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 7.1.33

System => Linux a03a8839fff2 4.15.0-112-generic #113-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 9 23:41:39 UTC 2020 x86_64
Build Date => Oct 25 2019 06:31:52
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc/php' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d' '--enable-option-checking=fatal' '--with-mhash' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-sqlite=/usr' '--with-sqlite3=/usr' '--with-curl' '--with-libedit' '--with-openssl' '--with-zlib' '--with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--with-apxs2' '--disable-cgi' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu'
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php
Loaded Configuration File => (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-bcmath.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-exif.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-gd.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-gmp.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-ldap.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-mysqli.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pcntl.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sysvmsg.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-zip.ini

PHP API => 20160303
PHP Extension => 20160303
Zend Extension => 320160303
Zend Extension Build => API320160303,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20160303,NTS
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Signal Handling => enabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => disabled

Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies


 _______________________________________________________________________


Configuration

bcmath

BCMath support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
bcmath.scale => 0 => 0

Core

PHP Version => 7.1.33

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
allow_url_fopen => On => On
allow_url_include => Off => Off
arg_separator.input => & => &
arg_separator.output => & => &
auto_append_file => no value => no value
auto_globals_jit => On => On
auto_prepend_file => no value => no value
browscap => no value => no value
default_charset => UTF-8 => UTF-8
default_mimetype => text/html => text/html
disable_classes => no value => no value
disable_functions => no value => no value
display_errors => STDOUT => STDOUT
display_startup_errors => Off => Off
doc_root => no value => no value
docref_ext => no value => no value
docref_root => no value => no value
enable_dl => On => On
enable_post_data_reading => On => On
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => no value => no value
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => no value => no value
expose_php => On => On
extension_dir => /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303 => /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303
file_uploads => On => On
hard_timeout => 2 => 2
highlight.comment => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font> => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font>
highlight.default => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font> => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font>
highlight.html => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font> => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font>
highlight.keyword => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font> => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font>
highlight.string => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font> => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font>
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_source => Off => Off
ignore_user_abort => Off => Off
implicit_flush => On => On
include_path => .:/usr/local/lib/php => .:/usr/local/lib/php
input_encoding => no value => no value
internal_encoding => no value => no value
log_errors => Off => Off
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
mail.add_x_header => Off => Off
mail.force_extra_parameters => no value => no value
mail.log => no value => no value
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
max_file_uploads => 20 => 20
max_input_nesting_level => 64 => 64
max_input_time => -1 => -1
max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000
memory_limit => 128M => 128M
open_basedir => no value => no value
output_buffering => 0 => 0
output_encoding => no value => no value
output_handler => no value => no value
post_max_size => 8M => 8M
precision => 14 => 14
realpath_cache_size => 4096K => 4096K
realpath_cache_ttl => 120 => 120
register_argc_argv => On => On
report_memleaks => On => On
report_zend_debug => Off => Off
request_order => no value => no value
sendmail_from => no value => no value
sendmail_path =>  -t -i  =>  -t -i 
serialize_precision => -1 => -1
short_open_tag => On => On
SMTP => localhost => localhost
smtp_port => 25 => 25
sql.safe_mode => Off => Off
sys_temp_dir => no value => no value
track_errors => Off => Off
unserialize_callback_func => no value => no value
upload_max_filesize => 2M => 2M
upload_tmp_dir => no value => no value
user_dir => no value => no value
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
variables_order => EGPCS => EGPCS
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
zend.assertions => 1 => 1
zend.detect_unicode => On => On
zend.enable_gc => On => On
zend.multibyte => Off => Off
zend.script_encoding => no value => no value
zend.signal_check => Off => Off

ctype

ctype functions => enabled

curl

cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.64.0
Age => 4
Features
AsynchDNS => Yes
CharConv => No
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => No
IDN => Yes
IPv6 => Yes
krb4 => No
Largefile => Yes
libz => Yes
NTLM => Yes
NTLMWB => Yes
SPNEGO => Yes
SSL => Yes
SSPI => No
TLS-SRP => Yes
HTTP2 => Yes
GSSAPI => Yes
KERBEROS5 => Yes
UNIX_SOCKETS => Yes
PSL => Yes
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtmp, rtsp, scp, sftp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.1.1d
ZLib Version => 1.2.11
libSSH Version => libssh2/1.8.0

date

date/time support => enabled
timelib version => 2016.05
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 2018.7
Timezone Database => internal
Default timezone => UTC

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
date.default_latitude => 31.7667 => 31.7667
date.default_longitude => 35.2333 => 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.sunset_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.timezone => no value => no value

dom

DOM/XML => enabled
DOM/XML API Version => 20031129
libxml Version => 2.9.4
HTML Support => enabled
XPath Support => enabled
XPointer Support => enabled
Schema Support => enabled
RelaxNG Support => enabled

exif

EXIF Support => enabled
EXIF Version => 7.1.33
Supported EXIF Version => 0220
Supported filetypes => JPEG,TIFF

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
exif.decode_jis_intel => JIS => JIS
exif.decode_jis_motorola => JIS => JIS
exif.decode_unicode_intel => UCS-2LE => UCS-2LE
exif.decode_unicode_motorola => UCS-2BE => UCS-2BE
exif.encode_jis => no value => no value
exif.encode_unicode => ISO-8859-15 => ISO-8859-15

fileinfo

fileinfo support => enabled
version => 1.0.5
libmagic => 522

filter

Input Validation and Filtering => enabled
Revision => $Id: 5a34caaa246b9df197f4b43af8ac66a07464fe4b $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
filter.default => unsafe_raw => unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags => no value => no value

ftp

FTP support => enabled
FTPS support => enabled

gd

GD Support => enabled
GD Version => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
FreeType Support => enabled
FreeType Linkage => with freetype
FreeType Version => 2.9.1
GIF Read Support => enabled
GIF Create Support => enabled
JPEG Support => enabled
libJPEG Version => 6b
PNG Support => enabled
libPNG Version => 1.6.36
WBMP Support => enabled
XBM Support => enabled
WebP Support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 1 => 1

gmp

gmp support => enabled
GMP version => 6.1.2

hash

hash support => enabled
Hashing Engines => md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256 sha384 sha512/224 sha512/256 sha512 sha3-224 sha3-256 sha3-384 sha3-512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost gost-crypto adler32 crc32 crc32b fnv132 fnv1a32 fnv164 fnv1a64 joaat haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5 

MHASH support => Enabled
MHASH API Version => Emulated Support

iconv

iconv support => enabled
iconv implementation => glibc
iconv library version => 2.28

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
iconv.input_encoding => no value => no value
iconv.internal_encoding => no value => no value
iconv.output_encoding => no value => no value

json

json support => enabled
json version => 1.5.0

ldap

LDAP Support => enabled
RCS Version => $Id: 5f1913de8e05a346da913956f81e0c0d8991c7cb $
Total Links => 0/unlimited
API Version => 3001
Vendor Name => OpenLDAP
Vendor Version => 20447

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
ldap.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited

libxml

libXML support => active
libXML Compiled Version => 2.9.4
libXML Loaded Version => 20904
libXML streams => enabled

mbstring

Multibyte Support => enabled
Multibyte string engine => libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation => disabled
libmbfl version => 1.3.2
oniguruma version => 5.9.6

mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.

Multibyte (japanese) regex support => enabled
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) backtrack check => On
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version => 5.9.6

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mbstring.detect_order => no value => no value
mbstring.encoding_translation => Off => Off
mbstring.func_overload => 0 => 0
mbstring.http_input => no value => no value
mbstring.http_output => no value => no value
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes => ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) => ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
mbstring.internal_encoding => no value => no value
mbstring.language => neutral => neutral
mbstring.strict_detection => Off => Off
mbstring.substitute_character => no value => no value

mysqli

MysqlI Support => enabled
Client API library version => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 38fea24f2847fa7519001be390c98ae0acafe387 $
Active Persistent Links => 0
Inactive Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile => On => On
mysqli.allow_persistent => On => On
mysqli.default_host => no value => no value
mysqli.default_port => 3306 => 3306
mysqli.default_pw => no value => no value
mysqli.default_socket => no value => no value
mysqli.default_user => no value => no value
mysqli.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect => Off => Off
mysqli.rollback_on_cached_plink => Off => Off

mysqlnd

mysqlnd => enabled
Version => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 38fea24f2847fa7519001be390c98ae0acafe387 $
Compression => supported
core SSL => supported
extended SSL => supported
Command buffer size => 4096
Read buffer size => 32768
Read timeout => 31536000
Collecting statistics => Yes
Collecting memory statistics => No
Tracing => n/a
Loaded plugins => mysqlnd,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password,auth_plugin_sha256_password
API Extensions => mysqli,pdo_mysql

mysqlnd statistics =>  
bytes_sent => 0
bytes_received => 0
packets_sent => 0
packets_received => 0
protocol_overhead_in => 0
protocol_overhead_out => 0
bytes_received_ok_packet => 0
bytes_received_eof_packet => 0
bytes_received_rset_header_packet => 0
bytes_received_rset_field_meta_packet => 0
bytes_received_rset_row_packet => 0
bytes_received_prepare_response_packet => 0
bytes_received_change_user_packet => 0
packets_sent_command => 0
packets_received_ok => 0
packets_received_eof => 0
packets_received_rset_header => 0
packets_received_rset_field_meta => 0
packets_received_rset_row => 0
packets_received_prepare_response => 0
packets_received_change_user => 0
result_set_queries => 0
non_result_set_queries => 0
no_index_used => 0
bad_index_used => 0
slow_queries => 0
buffered_sets => 0
unbuffered_sets => 0
ps_buffered_sets => 0
ps_unbuffered_sets => 0
flushed_normal_sets => 0
flushed_ps_sets => 0
ps_prepared_never_executed => 0
ps_prepared_once_executed => 0
rows_fetched_from_server_normal => 0
rows_fetched_from_server_ps => 0
rows_buffered_from_client_normal => 0
rows_buffered_from_client_ps => 0
rows_fetched_from_client_normal_buffered => 0
rows_fetched_from_client_normal_unbuffered => 0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_buffered => 0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_unbuffered => 0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_cursor => 0
rows_affected_normal => 0
rows_affected_ps => 0
rows_skipped_normal => 0
rows_skipped_ps => 0
copy_on_write_saved => 0
copy_on_write_performed => 0
command_buffer_too_small => 0
connect_success => 0
connect_failure => 0
connection_reused => 0
reconnect => 0
pconnect_success => 0
active_connections => 0
active_persistent_connections => 0
explicit_close => 0
implicit_close => 0
disconnect_close => 0
in_middle_of_command_close => 0
explicit_free_result => 0
implicit_free_result => 0
explicit_stmt_close => 0
implicit_stmt_close => 0
mem_emalloc_count => 0
mem_emalloc_amount => 0
mem_ecalloc_count => 0
mem_ecalloc_amount => 0
mem_erealloc_count => 0
mem_erealloc_amount => 0
mem_efree_count => 0
mem_efree_amount => 0
mem_malloc_count => 0
mem_malloc_amount => 0
mem_calloc_count => 0
mem_calloc_amount => 0
mem_realloc_count => 0
mem_realloc_amount => 0
mem_free_count => 0
mem_free_amount => 0
mem_estrndup_count => 0
mem_strndup_count => 0
mem_estrdup_count => 0
mem_strdup_count => 0
mem_edupl_count => 0
mem_dupl_count => 0
proto_text_fetched_null => 0
proto_text_fetched_bit => 0
proto_text_fetched_tinyint => 0
proto_text_fetched_short => 0
proto_text_fetched_int24 => 0
proto_text_fetched_int => 0
proto_text_fetched_bigint => 0
proto_text_fetched_decimal => 0
proto_text_fetched_float => 0
proto_text_fetched_double => 0
proto_text_fetched_date => 0
proto_text_fetched_year => 0
proto_text_fetched_time => 0
proto_text_fetched_datetime => 0
proto_text_fetched_timestamp => 0
proto_text_fetched_string => 0
proto_text_fetched_blob => 0
proto_text_fetched_enum => 0
proto_text_fetched_set => 0
proto_text_fetched_geometry => 0
proto_text_fetched_other => 0
proto_binary_fetched_null => 0
proto_binary_fetched_bit => 0
proto_binary_fetched_tinyint => 0
proto_binary_fetched_short => 0
proto_binary_fetched_int24 => 0
proto_binary_fetched_int => 0
proto_binary_fetched_bigint => 0
proto_binary_fetched_decimal => 0
proto_binary_fetched_float => 0
proto_binary_fetched_double => 0
proto_binary_fetched_date => 0
proto_binary_fetched_year => 0
proto_binary_fetched_time => 0
proto_binary_fetched_datetime => 0
proto_binary_fetched_timestamp => 0
proto_binary_fetched_string => 0
proto_binary_fetched_json => 0
proto_binary_fetched_blob => 0
proto_binary_fetched_enum => 0
proto_binary_fetched_set => 0
proto_binary_fetched_geometry => 0
proto_binary_fetched_other => 0
init_command_executed_count => 0
init_command_failed_count => 0
com_quit => 0
com_init_db => 0
com_query => 0
com_field_list => 0
com_create_db => 0
com_drop_db => 0
com_refresh => 0
com_shutdown => 0
com_statistics => 0
com_process_info => 0
com_connect => 0
com_process_kill => 0
com_debug => 0
com_ping => 0
com_time => 0
com_delayed_insert => 0
com_change_user => 0
com_binlog_dump => 0
com_table_dump => 0
com_connect_out => 0
com_register_slave => 0
com_stmt_prepare => 0
com_stmt_execute => 0
com_stmt_send_long_data => 0
com_stmt_close => 0
com_stmt_reset => 0
com_stmt_set_option => 0
com_stmt_fetch => 0
com_deamon => 0
bytes_received_real_data_normal => 0
bytes_received_real_data_ps => 0

openssl

OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
Openssl default config => /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
openssl.cafile => no value => no value
openssl.capath => no value => no value

pcntl

pcntl support => enabled

pcre

PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support => enabled
PCRE Library Version => 8.38 2015-11-23
PCRE JIT Support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit => 1000000 => 1000000
pcre.jit => 1 => 1
pcre.recursion_limit => 100000 => 100000

PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => sqlite, mysql

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 38fea24f2847fa7519001be390c98ae0acafe387 $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket => no value => no value

pdo_sqlite

PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
SQLite Library => 3.27.2

Phar

Phar: PHP Archive support => enabled
Phar EXT version => 2.0.2
Phar API version => 1.1.1
SVN revision => $Id: e117ab0dc068703c55b505e78a0d3b3752e9c0b7 $
Phar-based phar archives => enabled
Tar-based phar archives => enabled
ZIP-based phar archives => enabled
gzip compression => enabled
bzip2 compression => disabled (install pecl/bz2)
Native OpenSSL support => enabled


Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.
Directive => Local Value => Master Value
phar.cache_list => no value => no value
phar.readonly => On => On
phar.require_hash => On => On

posix

Revision => $Id: e3a2bc739dee8e0d29094e30e1cfbe3e87e2ceb4 $

readline

Readline Support => enabled
Readline library => EditLine wrapper

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
cli.pager => no value => no value
cli.prompt => \b \>  => \b \> 

Reflection

Reflection => enabled
Version => $Id: 279be19a9e466fb7cfea9841a630521f99644504 $

session

Session Support => enabled
Registered save handlers => files user 
Registered serializer handlers => php_serialize php php_binary 

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
session.auto_start => Off => Off
session.cache_expire => 180 => 180
session.cache_limiter => nocache => nocache
session.cookie_domain => no value => no value
session.cookie_httponly => Off => Off
session.cookie_lifetime => 0 => 0
session.cookie_path => / => /
session.cookie_secure => Off => Off
session.gc_divisor => 100 => 100
session.gc_maxlifetime => 1440 => 1440
session.gc_probability => 1 => 1
session.lazy_write => On => On
session.name => PHPSESSID => PHPSESSID
session.referer_check => no value => no value
session.save_handler => files => files
session.save_path => no value => no value
session.serialize_handler => php => php
session.sid_bits_per_character => 4 => 4
session.sid_length => 32 => 32
session.upload_progress.cleanup => On => On
session.upload_progress.enabled => On => On
session.upload_progress.freq => 1% => 1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq => 1 => 1
session.upload_progress.name => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix => upload_progress_ => upload_progress_
session.use_cookies => On => On
session.use_only_cookies => On => On
session.use_strict_mode => Off => Off
session.use_trans_sid => 0 => 0

SimpleXML

Simplexml support => enabled
Revision => $Id: ae067cdcddf424d6e762603905b98798bc924a00 $
Schema support => enabled
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in Dockerfile :

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
```

Comment: Please look at  MODIFIED BLOCK